# How to use Java nio to write an uploaded image from ServletInputStream?

Tags: nio

I've done the upload using ByteArrayOutputStream and now I want to use nio to write an image to a file in the hard disk from a ServletInputStream, I've tried a couple of ways but with no luck so far, now I have :

```
    @Override
public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)

throws IOException, ServletException {

    final String fileName = "img_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";

    final String filePathName = "E:\\tmp\\" + fileName;

    final FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(filePathName).getChannel();

    final ReadableByteChannel inChannel = Channels.newChannel(request.getInputStream());


       outChannel.transferFrom(inChannel, 0, request.getContentLength());



    inChannel.close();
    outChannel.close();

}
```

The specified file is generated with the same size as original, but cannot be opened. What have I done wrong here please? what is the proper way?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for the vague description. When I open the uploaded image, it says it is not a valid image file. And GraphicsMagick says :Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2d 0x2d.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the '--' is being put in the file, unless it is being sent to you, but you need to call `transferFrom()` in a loop. You can't assume the entire file is transferred in one call. It returns the number of bytes it transferred each call, so you can track the total number transferred: if it's complete, break, otherwise add that to the offset, subtract it from the length, and repeat.